# Unnesting columns in a JSON generated nested dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe created from JSON returned through an API.

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2020-09-10", "2020-09-09", "2020-09-08", 
                              "2020-09-07", "2020-09-06"), name = c("England", "England", "England", 
                                                                    "England", "England"), code = c("E92000001", "E92000001", "E92000001", 
                                                                                                    "E92000001", "E92000001"), cases = structure(list(daily = c(2578L, 
                                                                                                                                                                2286L, 2094L, 2528L, 2576L), cumulative = c(309133L, 306555L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            304269L, 302175L, 299647L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             -5L)), deaths = structure(list(daily = c(0L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 9L), 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            cumulative = c(36944L, 36944L, 36938L, 36930L, 36919L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -5L))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

If you take a look at the data with: `head(df)`

you get this:

```
       date    name      code cases.daily cases.cumulative deaths.daily deaths.cumulative
1 2020-09-10 England E92000001        2578           309133            0             36944
2 2020-09-09 England E92000001        2286           306555            6             36944
3 2020-09-08 England E92000001        2094           304269            8             36938
4 2020-09-07 England E92000001        2528           302175           11             36930
5 2020-09-06 England E92000001        2576           299647            9             36919
```

but

`colnames(df)`
gives:

`[1] "date"   "name"   "code"   "cases"  "deaths"`

I know there are 2 nested DFs in there, but I can't figure out how to use something like:

```
  unnest(cols = c(cases, deaths))
```

... to get 7 columns in an un-nested DF with the column names and structure as in the head example above. I'd prefer to be able to do this in a `tidyverse` pipe to avoid creating intermediate objects.

Comment: `do.call(cbind, df)` or even `do.call(data.frame, df)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

`do.call(cbind, df)`

Comment: This is a nice solution

Comment: It is and works - thanks.  Is there anything that works with pipes though?

Comment: You can do df %>% do.call(what = cbind) if you really want to use a pipe